# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, powershell, antbuilder, polarion

`An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20191203-1104\sources\ProjektNEU\templates.polarion\CIC\null\build.xml:869: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

I tried to run a new build in the Polarion ALM Software, but it throws out this Exception.
Does anyone know how to fix this Exception?

whole log:

````
2019-12-03 14:22:04,763 [Worker-0: Default build of templates.polarion:CIC | u:admin] INFO  root  - Status of job "Default build of templates.polarion:CIC" is FAILED:
BUILD ERROR

com.polarion.alm.builder.GenericBuilderException: BUILD ERROR

An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20191203-1418\sources\ProjektNEU\templates.polarion\CIC\null\build.xml:869: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20191203-1418\sources\ProjektNEU\templates.polarion\CIC\null\build.xml:861: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20191203-1418\sources\ProjektNEU\templates.polarion\CIC\null\build.xml:861: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20191203-1418\sources\ProjektNEU\templates.polarion\CIC\null\build.xml:861: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Polarion\data\workspace\polarion-data\jobs\20191203-1418\sources\ProjektNEU\templates.polarion\CIC\null\build.xml:861: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden```
````

Comment: PowerShell is built in on Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 and newer and should be in the `Path` by default. You will need to troubleshoot to determine why the `powershell` command is not available.

Comment: Hello,

I guess you are using a custom created Polarion Job, don't you? Can you provide please the code of it?